# Convert a String to a paired vector?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a string:

```
1,a,2,b,3,c etc
```

I want to convert it to a pair vector:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, QString> > myVector;
```

With 1 being the int and a being the string, 2 being the next int and b being the next string etc.

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow: doing your homework so you don't have to !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
  QString foo = "1,a,2,b,3,c";
  QStringList splits = foo.split(',');
  assert(splits.size() % 2 == 0); // check if even
  qDebug() << splits;

  std::vector< std::pair<int, QString> > vs;
  for(QStringList::const_iterator it = splits.begin(); 
      it != splits.end(); ++it) { 
    bool ok;
    QStringList::const_iterator tmp = it;
    ++it;

    vs.push_back(std::make_pair(tmp->toInt(&ok, 10), *it));
    assert(ok); // check if conversion worked
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: assert' was not declared in this scope

Comment: deleting that line and testing also causes app to crash

Comment: @user1013512 Oops. Include the header `cassert`. Also, fixed the crash.

Comment: If parsing external input, do not use assert() that it is correct. (and do not crash in release mode).

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Perfectly right. I just used that to show which invariants the code is assuming.